# Using NoSQL on a read-only filesystem

Tags: heroku

Heroku's [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-clojure#dyno-sleeping-and-scaling) suggest using NoSQL as one option, rather than Postgre. It is unclear to me exactly how this type of database allows data to persist in a filesystem like Heroku's that is essentially read-only for anything more than ephemeral.

Since NoSQL is usually a document store, where you are writing info out to a file, this doesn't make sense in the Heroku environment, does it? What exactly are Heroku's NoSQL doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not use your Dyno's file system to store SQL or NoSQL data. Persistence is provided by add-ons. Add-ons run on their own hardware, usually located inside Amazon's cloud, but are separate from your dynos.

So when you use a NoSQL (or SQL) add-on, you use some parameters (e.g. connection URL, username, password, etc) to communicate with it, and the NoSQL add-on stores the data according to its own architecture.

A dyno can have at most 1GB of RAM, but some add-ons provision lots of RAM. For example, the [Premium Mecha PostgreSQL add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) is $6000 per month and provisions 60GB of RAM for you. :)

For a list of various Heroku add-ons see [here](https://addons.heroku.com).